# How do I specify a project dependency with Hudson?

Tags: .net, msbuild, hudson

We have common library projects shared amongst many projects that are required to be checked out into a "Libraries" folder which a developer needs to checkout prior to opening the main project in visual studio.

How I tell hudson that there is this dependency?

I figured one thing I could do is setup a custom workspace and specify the location for all projects, but how do I wire up the dependency between them all? Is simply specifying "Build after other projects are built" enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward in Hudson; you just need to make sure that your "main" projects' build scripts pull the header files, compiled binaries etc. (whatever is needed for compilation) for the dependent libraries into an accessible location.  Then list each dependent library project in the "Build after other projects are built" field for each "main" project in Hudson, so that the "main" projects are rebuilt whenever one or more of the dependent libraries changes.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've set it up similar to this by specifying the working directory for each project in question, I couldn't seem to figure out how to get the main project to automatically pull the dependant projects as it doesn't seem possible.